# ReferenceError: event is not defined in my application when i am calling from jquery

Tags: jquery

When I am calling this function I am getting this error:

```
 if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
 ReferenceError: event is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
 $(".decimalonly").each(function () {
                    $(this).keydown(function (e) {


                        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||

                                    (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                                    ((event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 110) && $(this).val().indexOf(".") == -1) ||

                                    (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {

                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            keypress
                            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Corrected grammar and punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `e` to the function but in the function you're calling `event`. Replace `$(this).keydown(function (e)` with `$(this).keydown(function (event)` and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `e` as parameter then `e` variable contains all the event information. So replace every `event` with `e`. I also noticed `keypress` which should also cause an error because it is not defined anywhere, it is no an assignment or a function call.

Comment: @Abhishek Can you accept my answer as I was earlier than the accepted one and I also pointed out another mistake. Or at least an upvote.